# WCF Setting Security to None fails

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a service that is working fine using the default security (Windows as far as I know). But I need to enable mi service to work across different domains, so I am trying to disable security for test purposes.

Here's the original client :

Client app.config

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService">
                <security>
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://me.domain.local/MyService/Service.svc"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyService"
            contract="MyService.IMyService" name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="host/me.domain.local" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now, I set this security tag from **Windows** to **None** and I will need to to the same in the Service side but it seems that I'm failing to do so

Heres the original working app.config of the Service

```
    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyServiceWCF.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyServiceWCF.IMyService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyServiceWCF/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

I tried adding this tag but it would not work

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBindingConfig" transferMode="Buffered" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="5242880" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Edit 1 :**

So I corrected the client app.config code to set Security mode to None. I also try to use Net Tcp binding.

```
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="MyBinding">
              <security mode="None">
              </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://me.domain.local/MyService/Service.svc"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyService"
            contract="GService.IMyService" name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="host/me.domain.local" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
```

Now for the server side I tried this but wont work either. I really think Im missing a point here.

```
  <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

 <services>
      <service name="MyServiceWCF.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyServiceWCF.IMyService" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="MyServiceWCF.IMyService" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinging_IMyService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyServiceWCF/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change to tcp.
Just add a basic http endpoint for your service:

```
<endpoint address="http://rofl.lol" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingSettings" contract="roflservice" bindingName="BasicHttpBindingSettings/>
```

And set the security to none in you binding:

```
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding name="BasicHttpBindingSettings">         
           <security mode="None"/>
       </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but I got a error, that the client and the service do not have a matching security configuration. I changed                         <transport clientCredentialType="None" /> in the client and added this to the app.config in the service :    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingSettings" contract="MyServiceWCF.MyService" bindingName="BasicHttpBindingSettings"/>

Comment: You just changed the credential type, not the security mode.
In your client you are using tcp binding and in your server http. You have to change the client configuration to http too. And you have remove the "transport" element from the security. Security has a property "Mode" where you can select "None", or just remove the whole "security" element.

Comment: You are correct. But I intend to use Tcp binding. I'm editing the question to reflect this.